# Generate mongoose schema for dynamically populated array of objects

Tags: arrays, database, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

This is my array of objects:

```
 [
        {
            ready: true,
            body: "Body 1"
        },
        {
            ready: true,
            body: "Body 3"
        },
        {
            ready: true,
            body: "Body 3"
        },
    ]
```

Now if I want to generate a schema I'd normally do something like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const BodySchema = new Schema({

});

mongoose.model('Body', BodySchema);
```

I need to know what to put inside the `new Schema({});` declaration so it would accept the array of objects.

Thanks.

EDIT:

This is how I format data:

```
try {
        const retrievedFull = await getFullData();
        const data = await retrievedFull.map(({ready, body}) => ({
            ready,
            body
        }))

       const finalData = new Body(data) //instantiate Schema
       return res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            data: finalData
        })

    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
```

The response from `getFullData()`:

```
[
            {
                ready: true,
                body: "Body 1",
                other_stuff: "Stuff 1"
            },
            {
                ready: true,
                body: "Body 2",
                other_stuff: "Stuff 2"
            },
            {
                ready: true,
                body: "Body 3",
                other_stuff: "Stuff 3"
            },
        ]
```

So, basically I strip all the properties I want and make a new array of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the data you want to store in database are two simple attributes, you can use the following schema :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const BodySchema = new Schema({
    ready: Boolean,
    body: String,
});

const BodyModel = mongoose.model('Body', BodySchema);
```

---

About the way to store the data inside of the database :

```
try {
  // Get the data from an external source
  const externalData = await getFullData();

  // Format the data
  const formattedData = externalData.map(({
    ready,
    body,
  }) => ({
    ready,
    body,
  }));

  // Insert the data in the database
  const databaseData = await BodyModel.insertMany(formattedData);

  // Returns the inserted data
  return res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    data: databaseData,
  });
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

Documentation of [insertMany](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany)

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that as well... for some strange reason `data = [];` happens. I get empty array. Do you want to go for a chat over this?

Comment: You should edit your question and add how you are retrieving the data. And what tool do you use to know that there are data on your database?

Comment: I am using Robo 3T, previously Robomongo.

Comment: Edited, please check my question.

Comment: You should add the method `getFullData()` because we want to know how you perform your `.find`. And `console.log` the response made by it

Comment: I am not doing any direct call on the db. `getFullData()` calls external api source that fetches some random data. I will add the response example.

Comment: WORKS!! Thanks man!! I have completely forgot about `insertMany()`. It makes sense now..

Comment: Also, the problem with `insertMany()` is that it duplicates collection. Would be good if there are any alternatives...

Answer (score 0):

I would define it this way:

```
const BodySchema = new Schema({
    data: [{
        ready: Boolean,
        body: String
    }]
});
```